# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert' Python List append insert

Tags: python, list, insert, append

I have the following problem: 
I create an array and then I turned it to  a list, to which I want to add two more values. I have tried with append and with insert but I becoma the error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'. That means that my list is not a list. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
f = 25
bi = np.arange(-f, f + 5, 5)
beta = bi.tolist()
print "beta:", beta

d = np.arange(-f, f + 5, f / 3)
di = d.tolist()
print "di:", di

dj = di.insert(1, -f / 2)
print "dj:", dj 

dk = dj.insert(5, f / 2)
dw = sorted(dk)
delta = [round(elem, 0) for elem in dw]
print "delta:", delta
```

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong or how can Imake it work? Moreover the "sorted" seems also not to be working.

Comment: always add full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is on 9th line:
list insert method does not return anything (means None),

```
dj=di.insert(1,-f/2)
```

so **dj** will get assigned **None**
so this statement will raise an error.

```
dk=dj.insert(5,f/2)
```

Now Try This:

```
f=25
bi=np.arange(-f,f+5,5)
beta=bi.tolist()
print "beta:", beta
d=np.arange(-f,f+5,f/3)
di=d.tolist()
print "di:", di
di.insert(1,-f/2)
print "di:", di
di.insert(5,f/2)
dw=sorted(di)
delta=[round(elem, 0) for elem in dw]
print "delta:", delta
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. Although I don't get why in dj is assigned NONE. Is assigned di.insert.

Answer (score 1):

`insert()` and `append()` doesnt't return new list so you can't assign it to `dj`

```
di.insert(1,-f/2)

print "di:", di

di.insert(5,f/2)

print "di:", di

dw = sorted(di)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
dj=di.insert(1,-f/2)
dk=dj.insert(5,f/2)
```

`di.insert()` inserts something into the list `di` and returns `None`, so you're assigning `None` to `dj`.

THEN, you're trying to call the function `insert()` in the 'value' `None` which doesn't have it so you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's happening because di.insert() doesn't actually return anything and that's why dj is a NoneType object.

Do this instead

```
from copy import copy
dj=copy(di)
dj.insert(1,-f/2)
```

Comment: `dj` and `di` will be names for the same object.

Comment: Yeah that's why he needs a copy of the list. copy.copy should work. Provided OP wants a new copy of the list for whatever he's doing.